# How to convert 2010-07-28 00:00:00 to July 28, 2010, 00:00:00 using PHP

Tags: php, datetime

How to convert `2010-07-28 00:00:00` to `July 28, 2010, 00:00:00` using PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo date("F j, Y, H:i:s",strtotime('2010-07-28 00:00:00'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new DateTime('2010-07-28 00:00:00');
echo $date->format('F j, Y, H:i:s');
```

Comment: @Fero: It formats the DateTime object as a string. See http://php.net/datetime.format

Comment: @@Daniel: My version is 5.2.6. It doesn't support format. In this case what shall i do

Comment: @Faro: It was added in 5.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Use `date` and [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) functions:

```
$date = date("F d, Y, H:i:s",strtotime('2010-07-28 00:00:00'));
echo $date;
```

**Output:**

```
July 28, 2010, 00:00:00
```